# Repository browser in Mercurial

Tags: windows, mercurial, logging

I am using Mercurial Browser in Windows quite often. But now i need to check all the revision at the begining. For example i have 19 000 revisions - but only some of them are shown when i set all...

[http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/5195/browsery.th.png](http://img148.imageshack.us/i/browsery.png/)

So any idea how to do it - to show really all changes and revision not only x weeks ago? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG I am blind there are two buttons for that i have found it sorry :-)

http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/4226/answerq.png

My bad sorry :-( Hope someone will help this anyway ...